# Bluetooth crash intermittent

Tags: android, bluetooth

I have setup a bluetooth connection and used some of the code in bluetooth chat. I find there is an intermittent crash on startup. I think its due to startActivityForResults is not waiting for the connection. I saw some past threads where this was resolved but the poster did not share resolution.

[Android Bluetooth enable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9424756/android-bluetooth-enable)

I also cannot figure out how to post my logcat information so its formated for easy reading in the thread. I am using Android studio 1.3.1 and my options are print.

```
   void findBT() {
    mmDevice = null;
    BluetoothAdapter mBluetoothAdapter = BluetoothAdapter.getDefaultAdapter();
    if (mBluetoothAdapter == null) {
        //msbox("BlueTooth ", "This device does not support bluetooth");
        isBTConnected = false;
        // Bluetooth tile indicator
        Resources res = getResources();

    } else {

        if (!mBluetoothAdapter.isEnabled()) {
            Intent enableBluetooth = new Intent(BluetoothAdapter.ACTION_REQUEST_ENABLE);
            startActivityForResult(enableBluetooth,0);
        }
    }

    Set<BluetoothDevice> pairedDevices = mBluetoothAdapter.getBondedDevices();
    if (pairedDevices.size() > 0) {

        for (BluetoothDevice device : pairedDevices) {
            // if(device.getName().equals("RN42-45A9"))
            if (device.getName().equals("RN42-4485")) {
                Log.d("TAG", "BT true");
                mmDevice = device;
                isBTConnected = true;
                // Bluetooth tile indicator
                Resources res = getResources();

            } else {
                // Bluetooth tile indicator
                isBTConnected = false;
                Log.d("TAG", "BT false");
                Resources res = getResources();
            }
        }
    } else {
        isBTConnected = false;
    }
}

void openBT() throws IOException {
    UUID uuid = UUID.fromString("00001101-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb");

    mmSocket = mmDevice.createRfcommSocketToServiceRecord(uuid);
    mmSocket.connect();
    mmOutputStream = mmSocket.getOutputStream();
    mmInputStream = mmSocket.getInputStream();

    beginListenForData();

}
```

Logcat

```
08-22 13:32:13.781  11239-11314/com.example.jerry.els2015 W/dalvikvm﹕ threadid=12: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x41879c08)
08-22 13:32:13.781  11239-11314/com.example.jerry.els2015 E/AndroidRuntime﹕ FATAL EXCEPTION: Thread-502
    Process: com.example.jerry.els2015, PID: 11239
    java.lang.NullPointerException
            at com.example.jerry.els2015.MainActivity.GetData(MainActivity.java:1087)
            at com.example.jerry.els2015.MainActivity.access$300(MainActivity.java:44)
            at com.example.jerry.els2015.MainActivity$12.run(MainActivity.java:840)
            at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:841)
08-22 13:32:13.861  11239-11239/com.example.jerry.els2015 D/GC﹕ <tid=11239> OES20 ===> GC Version   : GC Ver rls_pxa988_KK44_GC13.20
08-22 13:32:13.901  11239-11239/com.example.jerry.els2015 D/OpenGLRenderer﹕ Enabling debug mode 0
08-22 13:32:13.911  11239-11239/com.example.jerry.els2015 D/ProgressBar﹕ updateDrawableBounds: left = 0
08-22 13:32:13.911  11239-11239/com.example.jerry.els2015 D/ProgressBar﹕ updateDrawableBounds: top = 0
08-22 13:32:13.911  11239-11239/com.example.jerry.els2015 D/ProgressBar﹕ updateDrawableBounds: right = 308
08-22 13:32:13.911  11239-11239/com.example.jerry.els2015 D/ProgressBar﹕ updateDrawableBounds: bottom = 50
08-22 13:32:13.911  11239-11239/com.example.jerry.els2015 D/ProgressBar﹕ updateDrawableBounds: mProgressDrawable.setBounds()
08-22 13:37:14.334  11239-11314/? I/Process﹕ Sending signal. PID: 11239 SIG: 9
```

Here is the connection code.

```
   void openBT() throws IOException {
    UUID uuid = UUID.fromString("00001101-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb");

    mmSocket = mmDevice.createRfcommSocketToServiceRecord(uuid);
    mmSocket.connect();
    mmOutputStream = mmSocket.getOutputStream();
    mmInputStream = mmSocket.getInputStream();

    beginListenForData();

}
```

Here is the getdata

```
    private void GetData(int FixtureNumber) {

    Log.d("TAG", "Value  " + intArrayToInt(intArray1));

    intByteCount=9;                         // set to receive 9 bytes

    byte buffer[] = new byte[6];

    buffer[0] = ((byte) 1); // Command (get data)
    buffer[1] = ((byte) Master_value);
    buffer[2] = ((byte) intArrayToInt(intArray1));
    buffer[3] = ((byte) intArrayToInt(intArray2));

    buffer[4] = ((byte) 3);
    buffer[5] = ((byte) 4);

    if (isBTConnected) {

        try {
            mmOutputStream.write(buffer);
        } catch (IOException e) {

            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    }
}
```

Comment: if your `mBluetoothAdapter ` is `null` it will still go to `mBluetoothAdapter.getBondedDevices()` this line. Which will result in a `NullPointerException`. I dont know if thats the issue. Can you tell us what was the exception?

Comment: Posted logcat Hopefully its formated

Comment: Still learning the bluetooth connection but from further study I think I am testing for adapter and then looking at paired devices that both do not  require an actual receiver to be true. I did however modify the paired devices to run only if mBluetooth adapter is true. My connection also seems to be without proof that the device is present. I have added the connection portion of the code to my initial post.

Comment: Show us the `GetData(...)` method.